# Can I use Django/Python API calls, and still use Javascript to manipulate the DOM in real time?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm in a full stack course and would like to use Django/Python to post/get my API calls, but use Javascript/Vue to stay on the same page. Can you still do that by essentially having a one page app that doesn't reload or change url? Just wondering before I go full on with it.

Also, what's a good way to use Javascript to get info onto the DOM from an API using an api key and secret key? I've experimented so much but haven't got back anything useful to my knowledge. Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) relevant in this context?

Comment: Yes a single page app is possible using Django. If you are using Django for API, [Django-RestFramework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is highly recommended.